# Finding Zip number from String

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

```
x = '''
Anrede:*
&#13;
&#13;
&#13;
Herr
*Name:*
&#13;
Tobias
*Firma:*

*Strasse/Nr:*
&#13;
feringerweg
*PLZ/Ort:*
&#13;
72531
*Mail:*
tovoe@gmeex.de [1]

&#13;
&#13;
&#13;

'''
```

In that there is a zip number *PLZ/Ort:*, this is zip number, i wanted to find the zip number from whole string, so the possible way is to use regex, but don't know regex,

Comment: What is the format of this zip number? Is it always (three uppercase letters)/(one uppercase letter)(two lowercase letters) etc? Before you can write the regex, you need to know what pattern you want to search for.

Comment: I think you should try to read the docs and some regex tutorial before asking a question here and post when/if you get trouble getting the results you're after.

Comment: *PLZ/Ort:*
&#13;
72531 here 72531 is zip number,

Comment: Just read about regular expression, and experiment. That's how you learn.

Comment: trying but having issue with &#13;

Comment: Extract the `*PLZ/Ort:* &#13; 72531` and then split by `;`? That's a bit longer but that gives you the result you want.

Comment: From your accepted answer, it seems to me that your zip number will always going to be numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input in your example is file with multiple strings, you can try something like this:

```
import re

for line in open(filename, 'r'):
    matchPattern = "^(\d{5})$"
    match = re.match(matchPattern, line, flags=0)
    print match.group(0) #the whole match
```

If this is just a long string, you can use the same match pattern but without `^` (line begin) and `$` (line end) indicators --> `(\d{5})`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the Postleitzahl always follows two lines that look like `*PLZ/Ort:*` and 
`&#13;`, and that it's the only text on its line.  If that's the case, then you can use something like:

```
import re
m = re.search('^\*PLZ/Ort:\*\n&#13;\n(\d{5})', x, re.M)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
(?<=PLZ\/Ort)[\s\S]+?([a-zA-Z0-9\- ]{3,9})
```

It will support Alpha numeric postal codes as well. You can see postal codes length/format from [here](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/help/cds2.asp?PID=8134).